# Populate new Pandas DataFrame in new format - lookup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe 'df1' with a simplified format of:

```
Hours   Material   Amount
10       Ni         .2
10       Mg         .6
10       Si         .25
20       Ni         .4
20       Mg         .9
20       Si         .6
30       Ni         .8
30       Mg         1.2
30       Si         .9
```

The actual data sets have more columns however the number of rows is determined by the number of hour samples 
(e.g. 3 rows per time sample).

I want to look at trends of material content over time, I tried to create an empty DataFrame 'df2' where columns are 'Material' and rows are 'Hours':

```
      Ni    Mg    Si
10    NaN   NaN   NaN
20    NaN   NaN   NaN
30    NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I can't find a way to populate the DataFrame with the respective data from 'df1'. I suspect there is a better way to do this, any suggestions?

Comment: @QuangHoang *I can't find a way to populate the DataFrame with the respective data from 'df1'.*

Comment: Interesting! Thank you @QuangHoang! I tried `df2 = pd.DataFrame({}, index=df1.Hours.unique(), columns=df1.Material.unique())` - But the cells still contain NaN. Any ideas?

Comment: You need pivot - `df.pivot('Hours','Material','Amount')`